# Regarding SQL Server DENY permission on a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions

RDBMS: SQL Server 2005

I am connecting to SQL Server through Windows Authentication.
My account(domain\me) belong to a group, "domain\alert"

The problem is that, even after denying a select permission on a table(actually all permissions), 
I could still access that table on a new connection.

> deny select on dbo.perm to [domain\me] 
>   GO

And one thing to note is that, the group i belong to, "domain\alert" is a dbo of database the table is located.

As far as I know, `deny` permission takes precedence over `grant`.

What permission can still be granting me a permission to `select` the `perm` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Books Online's [Permissions Hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191465(SQL.90).aspx):
[SQL Server 2005 Permissions Hierarchy http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms191465.dd24bb63-ab23-4f72-906f-ebc348fc64d8(en-US,SQL.90).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms191465.dd24bb63-ab23-4f72-906f-ebc348fc64d8(en-US,SQL.90).gif)
It looks like the Fixed database role takes precedence over the permissions given to a Windows Domain Login.  I also was under the impression that a `DENY` would always take precedence over a `GRANT`, but I guess Fixed database role `dbo` trumps all.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan.  I don't think I can argue with what the official doc reads ;)  It looks like it's just how it works.